# How to pass a Green Card through immigration to someone arriving to the US from abroad?

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration, paperwork, us-residents

My wife is travelling back to the US, but forgot to bring the green card with her during travel. So, it is still sitting at home in the US. Would there be a way for someone to bring her the green card behind immigration at the port of entry so she can use it to pass immigration?

Perhaps by mail, or perhaps someone could buy a cheap international flight and meet her there.

BTW, her port of entry is the Seattle airport. They have already allowed her to board.

Other relevant details that surfaced are - she has CR1 visa stamp in passport, but it is from September 2016. I posted a related question [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/112335/cr1-visa-stamp-expiration-with-2-year-date). I originally thought it better to keep the two lines of thinking separate for future readers.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75478/discussion-on-question-by-alex-k-send-a-green-card-behind-immigration).

Comment: Can you please let us know how this turned out?

Comment: @Mawg You can read my response below

Answer (score 53, accepted):

According to [CBP](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1191/kw/%22i%20forgot%20my%20green%20card%22/session/L3RpbWUvMTUyMjc2ODYyNi9zaWQvOXVDWnJmSm4%3D) it is very important for her to have her green card.

> Lawful Permanent Residents (LPR) of the U.S. must present a Permanent Resident Card ("Green Card", Form I-551), a Reentry Permit (if gone for more than 1 year), or a Returning Resident Visa (if gone for 2 years or more) to reenter the United States.

Since you're saying she has already boarded the plane, unless she is coming on a really long haul flight it might already be too late for courier.

The only option at this point I would think is to go to the airport and wait land side, communicate to her via email/text/Whatsapp etc to inform the CBP that she forgot her card at home and is available with her husband/someone else in the arrivals area.  If they like they will  be able to get to that.

**They will not refuse entry before verifying different options they have to assess her residence status** and the fact that her documentary proof is available with someone in the arrivals hall can only help, it can't hurt her chances.

What's still unknown is whether the card is close to Seattle airport or not. If the card also has to take a flight to reach there then unfortunately i think this question is being asked a little too late. **She will have to attend the landing interview without her green card and try to convince them about it.**

**Do not courier it now**, it is too late and it is far better to have it in someone's possession than to have it stuck in transit.

Since she has a valid visa which allowed her to board the plane, there are chances that **she will be admitted** under that status even if the green card can not get to her. In that case she will have to go to a deferred inspection site to get her admission status adjusted once she has the green card in her possession.

**Edit:**

It is by a stroke of luck that this passenger was allowed to board in the first place. **Future readers please note** that this may not work for you the same way. On the US port of entry you may get away with it with just a scolding but the port of departure may flat out refuse boarding and that is a much bigger problem. So my advice would be to arrange for your documentation to reach you before your departure for US.

Comment: I want to emphasize that last bit -- **make sure** you get the status fixed! Otherwise, even though she has a green card, it could cause serious issues down the line, and no one wants that.

Comment: With 20-20 hindsight, it might have been better to stay outside the US until the green card could have been delivered to her.

Comment: This answer is wrong. OP's wife has an Immigrant visa, which can be used for a year after the Initial entry instead of a green Card, even if the visa is expired (the valdiity Dates are only relevant for the first entry)

Comment: She doesn't have a valid visa (immigrant visas are single entry and her's is used) but a stamped immigrant visa serves as temporary I-551 for a year (it says so on the visa). I traveled twice with mine before the card arrived. If she's inside a year she is probably technically okay, though she'll likely still get crap for not carrying the actual card.

Comment: @Coke, is CR1 the same status as an LPR admission? If not, then what makes this answer wrong?

Comment: @HankyPanky: The answer is not wrong. It's just that based on the comments to the question, she already has what this answer says she needs -- she has an I-551 (the immigrant visa, upon being stamped on entry, turned into an I-551 valid for one year from the date of entry). A green card is also an I-551; what she has is the same thing, just in a different form. The OP just left out this important piece of information in the original question. So the rest of the answer assuming that she doesn't have it is not applicable, assuming it's less than one year since her initial entry.

Comment: This answer is not wrong. From [the OP's other question here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/112335/cr1-visa-stamp-expiration-with-2-year-date) the visa endorsement is a 2016 vintage so it is past the one year mark.

Comment: "random luck": I would attribute it rather to an improperly trained airline employee, but I would suspect that the vast majority of airline employees are ignorant of how immigrant visas work in the US.  I certainly don't recall seeing any material in timatic that covers a situation like this.

Comment: @phoog I agree but then if even the CBP Officer was confused about that handwritten date (as described in an answer by OP)  it was easy for check in staff to get confused as well even if they knew the actual limit was 1 year.

Comment: @phoog Many employees were contacted during the flight checkin. So it wasn't just one employee that was confused. Initially we were denied-perhaps the high emotions at that time pressured them to find alternative routes.

Comment: @AlexK I am not surprised.  If timatic says nothing about it, I would expect that anyone knowing how the system works would be a rare exception.  Anyway it worked out well for you in the end.

Answer (score 63):

My wife has arrived now and passed immigration successfully, so I can answer the question based on this one experience, although it won't necessarily be the same for everyone.

The direct answer - the green card wasn't needed in the end. She had a scanned version of the green card - the immigration officer said they don't accept scanned versions and didn't even look at it.

I called the airport and spoke with an immigration office before arrival. He was quite friendly, and said if she forgot the green card, they do have other options. He did emphasize, however, that he can't guarantee her entry until he meets her and has a discussion.

When my wife arrived, she spoke with this same officer. She said it didn't take very long (about 5 minutes), but the whole process of waiting in immigration - being sent to a private room to meet with this officer, and getting his approval -  took long enough that she missed the connecting flight. She had a 1 hour 20 minute layover.

It seems to me that the website wording is intended to appear strict to avoid such situations, but in reality flexibility exists. Calling before hand seemed to help show that it was an honest mistake.

It also seems that the result is up to the officer's discretion; luckily our officer seemed to be having a good day.

As some comments mention - if this happens to you, the hardest part will be boarding in the first place. We were fortunate in that her passport had a visa that was dated 2 years in the future instead of 1 year as it should be.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked out! I can't say I'm surprised about the connection, though. Even as a citizen, I rarely plan international-to-domestic layovers that short. I waited in line for immigration for about an hour at DTW back in the summer. And then around 2 hours to enter Canada at YYZ T3.

Comment: *"It seems to me that the website wording is intended to appear strict to avoid such situations, but in reality flexibility exists."* Pretty much like everything in life!

Comment: @reirab You might want to consider NEXUS, if you're eligible.  It will save you a ton of time at both US and Canada customs and immigration.

Comment: @JimMacKenzie Good advice. I don't personally need to enter Canada often, but if I did, I'd definitely have enrolled in Nexus. I'd have already enrolled in Global Entry, if the nearest enrollment center weren't 80 miles away and only open for a few hours in the middle of the day on weekdays. :/ I wish CBP would let contractors do GE enrollment interviews like DHS does with TSA PreCheck.

Comment: @reirab CBP will let you do a GE interview on return from a trip abroad, without appointment, if you clear customs at an airport that does them. Or do what we did with NEXUS, since it's half the price and better, and just plan a trip around the interview. We did our first interviews at Fort Erie, ON on a Niagara Falls visit, and our renewal ones while flying home CDG-YYZ-YQR (@YYZ). Renewals actually rarely require interviews anymore, we just got unlucky.

Comment: @JimMacKenzie Yeah, I'm planning to do the interview on arrival in a few weeks, actually. They started allowing that (for GE, anyway) after the trip I mentioned earlier. I'm just planning to do GE, though, as I have a card that reimburses the app fee anyway.

Comment: "CBP will let you do a GE interview on return from a trip abroad, without appointment, if you clear customs at an airport that does them" - Don't necessarily count on that, though. I attempted to do it once and was turned away.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to the [advice given in Hanky Panky's answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/112336/12011), if she has a smartphone or other portable electronic device that can access a data network with her, it can't hurt for you to take a picture of her green card and send it to her. They'll probably still want to see the real thing (and, thus, Hanky Panky's advice of trying to meet at the airport with the actual green card is still good advice,) having a picture of the card in her possession can only help her case.

Comment: The immigration officer said they don't accept it and didn't even look. It could be different for someone else...Like you said, it couldn't hurt.

Comment: @AlexK even if the immigration officer didn't look at it, having it could still help show good faith.

Answer (score 7):

I cross US-Canada border 3-4 times a week for my work. Once I forgot my Canadian PR card and only realized after crossing into the US. On my way back, I explained the situation to border officer. He told me to park and speak with a different officer. I showed them my driving license and passport and after few simple questions, they allowed me to enter into Canada after verifying it from their systems.

What I was told by border officers which also applies to US green card is that these cards are the important proof that you are a legal resident, BUT they aren't the only proof. If you can prove to officers that you are a legal resident by some documents (like driving license), they will have to let you get into the country because that's where your home is, where else would they send you? But these are extraordinary situations and should not be misused.

Comment: This is absolutely true if you can get to a border officer. The issue when you are overseas and need to fly home is that the airline won't let you get on the plane to get to the border officer (in the current case the airline screwed up). The cure for this for a US LPR is to visit a consulate, get that officer to verify your status and then buy a transportation letter from her (for a punative $575),  which is the same thing but way more expensive and inconvenient.

Comment: This happened to me as well trying to get back into the US from Canada. I didn't bring my greed card. It took all of 15 minutes to straighten out.

Answer (score 6):

Edit: This answer made sense for the original question but is not relevant after that was edited.

Without evidence that she has the right to enter the USA, she may not be allowed to board her flight in the first place.

I would use a courier such as FedEx and send the card to her.

Comment: Good point! I edited the tense and specified - she has already boarded actually. So it's too late to FedEx or otherwise send the card internationally.

Comment: At this point I'd go to the airport and ask the border staff what to do.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: apparently the temporary I-551 was expired, in which case beats me how she got on the plane

Old answer:

The CR1 visa, even if expired, can be used for entry instead of a green card for a year after the first entry on it. Check-in staff knew this (it even says on the visa) and thus let her board.

So she'll be just fine, and you don't have to do anything.

Comment: Does it remain valid for use after it has been replaced by an actual green card?

Comment: Can you provide references? Because the website says **six** months from entry date. _Passport(s) valid for six months beyond the intended date of entry into the United States, unless longer validity is specifically requested by the U.S. Embassy/Consulate in your country. Please review the instructions for guidance_ [Dept. of State Website](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/immigrate/family-immigration/immigrant-visa-for-spouse.html)

Comment: @TheZealot the text you quote has to do with passport validity required to *apply for* an immigrant visa.  It says nothing about the validity of the endorsed immigrant visa serving as a temporary I-551 after its first use.  And an LPR with a valid I-551 doesn't even require a passport, let alone a valid one.

Comment: @phoog Yes it does.

Comment: @Coke do you have any support for that assertion?

Comment: @phoog Says clearly on the visa, making no mention of the card delivery. Plus, is the USCIS really notified when the card arrives by post (do you have to put your signature when collecting it?)?

Comment: I don't know.  *I'm* convinced by your arguments, but I'm not convinced that all immigration officers would be.  For all I know, there might indeed be a database indication that the LPR has been issued a green card.  I have no idea what would happen in such a case.  For @AlexK's wife, I suppose the best one can do is hope that either you're right or the immigration officer is sympathetic as was the case for [ILikeTacos](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/112332/send-a-green-card-behind-immigration/112344?noredirect=1#comment273700_112332).

Comment: @phoog Worst case, as I see it, is they'll be delayed for max 15 minutes and (unjustifiably) scolded

Comment: According to [OP's other question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/112335/12011), she entered the USA in 2016, therefore the temporary I-551 is now expired.