# In Timatic, is a scan (copy) of a green card good enough to board?

Tags: usa, air-travel, paperwork, check-in, us-residents

Say you have for example, a German passport, but you have US residency - so one of these:

[image]

You're going to fly from, say, Asia back to the US. You reach the airport and the airline is about to decide if you are allowed to board or not for the flight to the US. ("Docs OK!") Can you use a photo of the card on your phone to board, per the Timatic rules airlines use?

(Note that it's well-known that in the US, they'll let you enter after some fuss - they just look up that you have one. This question is strictly about whether the airline will let you board).

There was once [a question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/112372/19233) about a woman in this situation, BUT she actually boarded using an old tourist visa in per passport, which was just lucky. So as yet there's no real-life example here.)

I'm wondering whether the actual Timatic "rule" is that you need the plastic original? (Just as with driver's licenses, many folks just carry around only a copy of these, leaving the original safe somewhere.)

Maybe someone here does this all the time, answering the question.

Comment: A scan or copy would be trivially easy to fake.

Comment: @phoog The only cases where I could see it working are 1. when travelling by land to a country where you enjoy freedom of movement (a scan of my lost ID card got me by coach from Switzerland to Sweden, with checks at every border); 2. when travelling by air, if Timatic explicitly allows copies in your specific case.

Comment: @Coke in general a copy can be helpful in any situation where the authenticity of the copy could be verified by a database lookup. I presume that any situation where Timatic allows copies is such a situation.  I doubt there are many of these.

Comment: @phoog Or, most commonly, the copy is to be accompanied by something in original. As you say, copies are easy to fake, and at the risk of getting subjective, if it weren't for the fact that the rulers of Europe seek to virtually move the whole third world here, I doubt my ID scan would've been accepted as proof of nationality without further ado, especially as I don't look Nordic, even with me being fluent in the language at every border crossing.

Comment: @phoog old bean, there are many cases where you show only an electronic copy of something (on your phone) to the checkin agent, to show that you are docs-ok.  i's completely commonplace.  actually very often you **need only give the relevant ID number**.

Comment: @Fattie Completely commonplace? In what part of the world? Certainly not here in Europe.

Comment: @Fattie Yes, there are some countries that issue only e-visas (or "we won't call it a visa" electronic permission to visit a country systems like ESTA or ETA). Those can usually be verified electronically, though sometimes you have to show the confirmation. But that only applies in situations where the entire process is electronic. If an actual paper document is issued, airlines aren't going to accept a photo of it instead of the original document.

Comment: @Fattie sure, for systems like electronic boarding passes it's commonplace. Airlines, after all, maintain their own databases about their passengers and the passes they've been issued. But for travel documents, there are two considerations against this: first, many (most?) countries' laws continue to require the traveler to have a physical document, and second, airlines do not have access to databases that would allow them to confirm document authenticity based on the number. E-visa systems, again, are designed for this, but online verification of LPR status would be fraught with difficulty.

Comment: "they rarely verify them electronically": this is certainly not the case for ESTA. The airline employee doesn't verify it electronically, but the airline's computer does: it passes the passport number to the US government, which responds with a message indicating whether it's okay to board the passenger. The government's system determines whether the person has ESTA authorization by querying its database using the passport number. A similar system for confirming the a green card holder's status does not exist. I suspect that other countries' similar systems (eTA, e-visas, etc.) work similarly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

All documents mentioned in TIMATIC must be originals, unless it's explicitly stated that a copy is accepted. There's no such statement regarding green cards.

So no, a copy of a green card will not do. And the German passport will be useless, as firstly it's not needed for a US permanent resident, and secondly entering on the basis of it requires a visa or ESTA, which a permanent resident cannot get.

Comment: great - super information!

Comment: @Fattie To clarity one point, **TIMATIC does not make any rules**, they merely aggregate rules from the relevant agencies and publish them.  If any agency allows 'copies' TIMATIC would merely reflect this.

Comment: @Johns-305 Exactly, they get their info from dedicated government sources on actual practice at airports, though I know that their sources in a few countries (such as Denmark) don't know what they're talking about with regards to specific regulations (which I once fell victim to - the culprit was Italy)

Comment: quite, @Johns-305 - in practice Timatic is precisely what the checkin staff of airlines use to decide if you are "Docs-OK" to fly to your final destination.

Comment: @Fattie Yes, and it's hard to get them to override Timatic. I'm flying from Edinburgh to the Faroe Islands with a French citizen who only has an ID card, and IATA's Danish sources have erroneously informed them that non-Nordic EU ID cards aren't valid for the Faroes. As such I e-mailed the station manager of Swissport (the check-in company) at Edinburgh, asking if a signed confirmation e-mail from the Faroese police with contact details would suffice to make them override Timatic. Fortunately she replied in the positive. So in such cases, always contact the ground handler in advance

Comment: Being a permanent resident without possession of your original green card is [illegal](https://www.uscis.gov/ilink/docView/SLB/HTML/SLB/0-0-0-1/0-0-0-29/0-0-0-8289.html) and punishable by up to 30 days in jail. Regardless of how enforced this actually is, I highly doubt that TIMATIC is going to say to do something that will technically land you in jail.